# Search column and return row elements in nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array with inner arrays:

```
var testdata1= [
  ["1001","55","58"],
  ["1002","64"],
  ["1003","73","76","77"],
  ["1004","81","84"],
  ["1005","97"],
];
```

What I want is to find a row by 1st column, then put all the other elements in that row into a new array. So if I searched `"1003"` I'd get:

```
newarray = [["73","76","77],];
```

After 3 hours of fruitless searching I'd really appreciate if someone could put me out of misery and show me the best way to do this. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This just needs a loop to find the row and another loop to copy the elements into a new array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop like below. This code loops through the array, checks if the first element in the current array is the number you wanted, and if so, adds the all the values of that array (except the first one) to the output array.

```js
var testdata1 = [
  ["1001", "55", "58"],
  ["1002", "64"],
  ["1003", "73", "76", "77"],
  ["1004", "81", "84"],
  ["1005", "97"],
];
var searchNumber = 1003;
var output = [];

testdata1.forEach(e => {
  if (e[0] == searchNumber) {
    output.push(e.slice(1));
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm feeling dumb.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Silverburch your welcome. Accept the answer whichever answer helped you the most, so others know that as well

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from the question what you want to do if there's more than one match. If you only care about the first match use the **find** method, if you want all the matching rows use **filter**. **find** returns a single row, **filter** returns a new array with all the matched rows.

If you want to discard the key column you can use a spread operator (as @Shidersz suggests), or the slice method.

e.g.

```
let hits = arr.filter(row => row[0] === "1004")
           .map(row => row.slice(1));
```

Should return hits = [["81","84"]];

You'll probably then want to decide what to do if the resulting array is either empty or contains more than one match.

The **filter** returns a new array of matched rows, the **map** then goes through this array and creates a new one, each element of which is the row with the first column removed.

This kind of "stream" processing is tending to supersede explicit loops. Arguably it's clearer once you get the hang of it.

Read through [JavaScript array reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

If you haven't already

Comment: This is actually very useful input and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
var testdata1= [
  ["1001","55","58"],
  ["1002","64"],
  ["1003","73","76","77"],
  ["1004","81","84"],
  ["1005","97"],
];

const findByFirstCol = (arr, colVal) =>
{
   let [first, ...rest] = arr.find(x => x[0] === colVal) || [,"Nothing found"];
   return [rest];
}

console.log(findByFirstCol(testdata1, "1003"));
console.log(findByFirstCol(testdata1, "1009"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: `findByFirstCol(testdata1, "1006")`

Comment: Great alternative - but unfortunately a little hard for my poor brain!

Comment: @Silverburch Don't let the code scare you, you can learn how to use those features in some future. Thanks anyway!